# Javafx gridpane margin with columns

Tags: javafx, alignment, margins, gridpane

I'm using a gridpane and the second row has 4 columns. Is it possible to align them with the rows that has 3 columns? I've looked around a lot and haven't found a solution for this yet.

Here is an image of the visual

[image]

Comment: You mean, the second row to have the same "width" as the first? To shrink the second row?

Comment: Exactly, I want Overwrite to be right after the checkbox and so on.

Comment: This can be solved by using a `HBox` as second element containing the checkbox and the Overwrite(label?) in the second row, then you get a 3 element row, and it is getting aligned to the first row as you want. Could this be a solution?

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! Thank you, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: It looks like your second row has five, not four, columns. Another solution is to set the column span for the text fields to 3, and make all the buttons have the same column index. That avoids the need of an extra `HBox`.

Comment: Post your layout code or `FXML`.